# How to show one line text in <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my html, I set a table column as 35%. I want to display one line of a text in the `<td>`, and any characters exceeding the width of column are chop off. I tried using `text-overflow:clip`. But if there are `<br>` in the text, it will show multiple lines.

I tested the answers I got. It seems not working. I think the only way is cut the text before display it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div .test").css("background-color","yellow");
  $("div .test").css("text-overflow","clip");
  $("div .test").css("white-space","nowrap");
  $(".test br").css("display", "none");
//  $("div .test").css("overflow":"hidden");

});
</script>
</head>
<body>    

<table>
<tr>
<td>testing</td>
<td>
<div style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
<p class="test">This is a paragraph.</p>
<span class="test">Skin or subcutaneous tissue or mucous membrane,repair of wound, other than wound closure at time of surgery, on face or neck,more > 7cm.</span>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Comment: Define *one line of a text*

Comment: demo fiddle will be better to help

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like you don't want the text to wrap, but to be chopped off at the edges of the column instead.

Add this to your `td` to get that effect:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow:hidden;
```

See:
http://jsfiddle.net/3948a/1/

Answer (score 3):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Nkj4b/3/)**

```
td{
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

`white-space:nowrap` will be the fix for it. And if your text in td contains `<br/>` tags we can ignore it by adding `display:none`.

```
td br{
    display:none;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/RH8V4/) :  max-width should be defined in px

```
 td {
   max-width: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
   text-overflow: clip;
   white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use CSS:

```
text-overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving a max width or max height for your `<td>` using CSS

```
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this will be like this 
`overflow-X:hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

HTML

Try to define the td width in pixel :

```
<table border=1 style="width:300px">
   <td style="max-width:100px">This is one line <br> text with out br
   </td>
   <td style="width:65%;">Another td
   </td>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td{
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

td br{
    display:none;
}
```

It will help

Answer (score 0):

you might be use below code in your css

```
.demo{
  word-wrap:break-word;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Thanks